# Is it possible to access the ASP.NET HttpSession by using WPF XBAP Application?

Tags: .net, wpf, xbap

I have a .xbap application and ASP.NET running on the same IIS server. And I did a login session from ASP.NET, but in my XBAP Application it must login again to access to this system. I want to use this ASP.NET Session to be a session of whole application including XBAP Application. This is a very large application. I don't want to change my login system.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I feel that this is not possible.
XBAP is just a WPF application running in the browser context, but doesnt have any capablities or cookie sharing like other ASP.NET apps. So there is no easy way to impresonate that ASP.NET authetication to the XBAP application context.